# C#でNTLM認証をしてHTTP通信をする方法

Tags: c#, http, iis, ntlm認証

タイトルの通りです。
これが実現できるクラスは存在しますか？

やりたいことは、Windows認証があるWebページの負荷テストです。

Comment: ADに参加しないクライアントから独自に認証を突破する方法を知りたい、という意味ですか。

Comment: auth SPNEGOを要求すればLANMAN認証にフォールバックされると思いますが。